# TFS Database - Get list of files in collection

Tags: tfs

Im trying to query the TFS database to get a list of all files held in the collection.

We use TFS as our version control for VS Solutions and Im trying to get a print out of files in each collections and whether they are checked in or not.
Ive got the ones that are still checked out but cant find the checked in ones

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: You should not query against the TFS operational store. Use the data warehouse.

Comment: you can query all the files without directly going into the Database, instead use TFS APIs. You need to find the files by traversing the collections, then projects then files. Once you have the files you can get the history info. This  can be done with C#.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind getting it from a list in tbl_LocalVersion. Not ideal but should suffice